# How can I log which processes create handles to a specific file?

Tags: windows, debugging

I am aware of `Sysinternals Process Explorer` which gives me a list processes having a handle to a specific file. But procexp.exe is not the right tool, as I think it might miss transient processes. Also there is no logging option.

So to keep it short: How can I log/monitor which processes are accessing a file over a period of time (e.g. 2 weeks)?

Comment: Have you looked at auditing?

Comment: In what way is this programming related? This is looking for a software tool or this is a question for SuperUser. Please clarify. Otherwise, look at Process Monitor and set a narrow filter